# Servlets in Maven

Tags: maven, servlets, web.xml

In the Maven Webapp project, I created the servlet `DiaServlet` in the root directory of the project, i.e., the directory where `pom.xml` is.

Its description in `web.xml` is as follows:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>DiaServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>DiaServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>DiaServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/DiaServlet</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

To this, I am getting the error:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: DiaServlet
```

One thing I tried is changing `<servlet-class>` tag to

```
    <servlet-class>Prj.base.DiaServlet</servlet-class>
```

Here, `Prj.base` is the `groupId` of the project in the `pom.xml` file-- if this would be any concern(?)

```
<groupId>Dia.base</groupId>
```

The same servlet `web.xml` definition worked as is in a "non-Maven" web application.

When I created the servlet (I'm using NetScape), the servlet description wasn't added to the `web.xml` file although I'd checked to add it automatically.

Is this a problem of the build environment, or my servlet definition in `web.xml` (if so, how come the same definition worked in the other web application?) or something else?

new to Maven

TIA

Comment: If your project is maven based so you must follow maven structure and you should define you servlet class's  whole path (after `src/majn/java` which is already known by maven). So if the structure of your maven project is correct, the issue is with `web.xml`

Comment: Maven has conventions, that you must respect. Java source files go into src/main/java. Not in the root directory. And NEVER, NEVER put your classes in the default package. That's a bad practice that will only get you troubles.

Comment: @pmp I only have `resources` and `webapp` under `src/main`. I created & built the prj on Netbeans.

Comment: This might help http://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/maven-in-five-minutes.html look at the hierarchy of theproject directory

Comment: You must have `java` package as well

Comment: @pmp java is not a package. It's a directory. The OP is already confused about packages. No need to add more confusion :-)

Comment: @JBNizet from java point of view is package and from maven point of view is directory. Anyways, we all know what we are talking about so let's not discuss on the namings. :)

Comment: @pmp no, that's incorrect. If you put a a Java file under src/main/java/com/foo, its package must be `com.foo`. See, no 'java' in the package name. So java is a directory containin source files. It's not a package.

Comment: @JBNizet you donot add `src/main/java` because maven will do it for you. It is cinsidered as default path for your java packages. So anyway, you can say it is a folder or directory which is more accurate. package might confuse people which you correctly mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

You are a maven user, at the time of initialization of your project, you are giving package name as Dia.base, so your classes are resides in the Dia.base package only

So,

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>DiaServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>Dia.base.DiaServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>DiaServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/DiaServlet</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

you need to give the fully qualified class name in the `<servlet-class>`